# Samba 4.6.5 compile errors on RHEL 7.3

Tags: compiler-errors, rhel, samba

When I try to compile Samba 4.6.5 on RHEL 7.3, I receive the following error:

```
In file included from ../source4/lib/socket/netif.h:22:0,<P>
                 from ../python/pyglue.c:24:<P>
../lib/replace/system/network.h:91:21: fatal error: stropts.h: No such file or directory<P>
 #include <stropts.h>
                     ^<P>
compilation terminated.<P>
Waf: Leaving directory `/root/Downloads/samba-4.6.5/bin'<P>
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1):<P>
        {task: cc pyglue.c -> pyglue_6.o}<P>
make: *** [all] Error 1<P>
```

The Python used is anaconda 2.7-4.4.0.  At the configure step, I get these warnings:

- no suitable FAM library found
- Building without DMAPI support: no
  suitable DMAPI library found

However, it completes successfully, saying:

> 'configure' finished successfully

Any clues on where to start troubleshooting?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my own question.  The header, stropts.h is definitely missing.  However, if I add the missing stropts.h at the top level of the samba source tree (e.g., where the 'configure' and Makefile scripts reside,) it successfully compiles.

I think this just needs an adjustment to point to a valid stropts.h or to include it in the tarball.